# LATEX paper size

Tags: latex

I can't get paper size working with a custom width and height in cm. DVI and even PDF then when they are generated are US Letter.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=5cm,height=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

    \title{Some title} 
    \author{Some author} 
    \maketitle 

    \lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I could use but I cant find a way to make it in cm. The result I wanted was x by y in cm PDF or dvi file.

```
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
```

Thnx in advance folks :)

Comment: I found this \special{papersize=7.444in,9.681in} but i have problems now with margins in document. Everything is messed up now.

Comment: Belongs on Tex and LaTeX (currently in beta).

Comment: @Tadeusz: latex questions continue to be on-topic here. Mitja might want to try [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) for a faster answer, but that does not make this post a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) provides pretty detailed information about your question.

If you use these options:

```
\usepackage[top=tlength, bottom=blength, left=llength, right=rlength]{geometry}
```

It should manage the margins automatically for you, but for your reference,  all of the page dimensions are measured from a single datum in each direction, so the even margin is actually determined from \paperwidth, \hoffset, \oddsidemargin, and \textwidth.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution. I would delete the topic but I can't. Murphey. I found the solution as soon as I posted it here.

```
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips]{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={7.444in,9.681in},total={4.8in,6.8in}}
```